# (shared host solution)protect subdirectory in document root except one folder within it (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory, document-root

I need to install "Laravel" in the "Public_html folder" because I am on a shared host.
The Laravel documentation gives a [solution](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1258)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

that will redirect everything to the "public" folder within the main "Laravel folder" that I have put in the "Public_html folder", you follow?

Can I still keep the "parent folder" of the "public folder" protected with htaccess?
Normally I would work with my own little frontcontroller framework and I just realised that I have never protected any of the subfolders that needed protection in Public_html.

What options do I have here in terms of protecting subfolders, but keeping in mind that I use a shared host? With Laravel it must be more complicated?or with any of the other frameworks if they operate in the same way?

[Laravel documentation](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1258)

thanks in adv